# How to disable feeds URL's validation?

Tags: uri

I am working with Facebok Graph API and I am using FQL queries to get to the data. I am handing those API calls through URLs. Drupal's default URL perceive them as invalid URLs maybe because they have a lot of special symbols like `" ) + , [`

How do I disable or override Drupal's URL validation for specified form?

Comment: And why not to urlencode special characters? [RFC 2396](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396) shows `[` in unwise group, `+` and `,` are simply reserved. Only on your list `)` is unreserved and can really be used. It means if you will continue to use `+ , [` in your URIs, proxies and other web software will be free break your transfer and you will not be entitled to blame them.

Comment: If you want simply to know how to change validation rules, it was already answered here.

Comment: @Mołot would be... where? I am sorry for asking after such a long period of tie jet I have just cam back to this project so...

Comment: Dammit. I remember I found it then. I can't find it now. I'm really really sorry I didn't post link back then :( as a side note - I never voted to close your question.